# C, Socket, pthread: read doesn't work on a new thread

Tags: c, sockets

I'm making a client-server program in C using threads.
I've got this problem: on the server, on thread #1 (number_one), function "read" works fine. But when I create another thread #2 (number_two), on this one something goes wrong. Parameters are passed in the right way (I think).

-->thread number_one

```
...   
        char message[256];
        int new_connection=accept(master_sock,NULL,NULL);
        pthread_t temp

        if(pthread_create(&temp , NULL , number_two , (void*) &new_connection))
        {
            perror("pthread_create failed");
            exit(-2);
        }
        else
        {
            puts("number_two created");
            if(read(new_connection, message, 256) > 0)
            printf("Message from client is %s", message);
        }
        if(pthread_detach(temp))
        {
            perror("detach failed");
            exit(-3);
        }
```

...

---> thread number_two

```
void *number_two(void *sock_desc)
{
    int sock = *(int*)sock_desc;

    int read_size;
    char client_message[2000];  

    read_size=read(sock, client_message, 256);
    client_message[read_size]='\0'; 

    return 0;
}
```

In "number_one", read waits an input from the client, and then it sets correctly the buffer "message".

In "number_two", read does not wait the client and does not set the buffer "client_message".

Thank you.

Comment: The parameter `sock_desc` can be defined in function definition/declaration of `number_two` as `int *` so you won't have to cast then dereference. As thread `number_two` starts, copy the value dereferenced from `sock_desc`. This is necessary as the value of `new_connection` may change before `read`ing `sock_desc`. Use `recv()` instead of `read()` when reading from sockets. Messages received on sockets can only be read once. The message is dequeued as soon as successfully read.

Comment: thanks, I've applied your advices but unfortunately the problem persists.

Comment: Only one of the threads will be able to read the message from the socket. If you want number_two to be able to read the message, remove the line from number_one that reads the message.

Comment: Yeah, my bad, that was my intention, i put The "read" line on number_one only for testing purposes. Without number_one line, the number_two line still does not wait client's message

Comment: 'printf("Message from client is %s", message);' printffing a C-string from a buffer that is not guaranteed null-terminated.    This is somewhat strange since, in the client<>server thread function, you add a terminating null with 'client_message[read_size]='\0';, but then do nothing with it:(

Comment: What is 'tmp_worker'?

Comment: Martin:
1st comment) you're right, in this code that line is useless. I've cut some lines after the read (number_two), 'cause the real problem is that read does not wait and goes on.

2nd comment): I've edited it, it's the same "temp" of pthread_create. Excuse me.

Comment: `number_two()` does not check the return value from `read()`, which could signal an error.  And `read()` works fine with sockets, by the way.  It's ok to use `recv()` instead, but you certainly don't need to do.

Comment: John: all you've written is true! However, read in number_two costantly goes on without stopping.

Comment: Are you expecting `thread_two` to wait before reading successive messages? Because it won't. Socket reads will continue with or without content. You will need to check the return value of `read()`. When `accept()` returns, it means the returned file descriptor is ready for reading. When `thread_two` starts, it will not wait, it will just `read()` whatever is available to read. By the way I am assuming you have BLOCKING I/O. If you implement non-blocking I/O, don't use `accept()`, use `poll()` or `select()`.

Comment: `new_connection` is a  local variable that may go out of scope.  Try passing the argument through a global or a malloc'd variable and see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: thank you both for your advices, I'll keep them in mind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try my code? it works, I think it is the same with your code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <net/if.h>
#include <netdb.h>

#define INVALID_SOCKET_FD  (-1)



int create_tcp_server_socket(unsigned short port, bool bind_local, int backlog,
        char *caller_name)
{
    int socket_fd = INVALID_SOCKET_FD;
    struct sockaddr_storage server_addr;

    unsigned int yes = 1;

    // just try ipv4
    if (socket_fd < 0 && (socket_fd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) >= 0) {
        struct sockaddr_in *s4 = (struct sockaddr_in *)&server_addr;
        setsockopt(socket_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &yes, sizeof(yes));
        memset(&server_addr, 0, sizeof(server_addr));
        s4->sin_family = AF_INET;
        s4->sin_port = htons(port);
        if (bind_local)
            s4->sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_LOOPBACK);
        else
            s4->sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);

        if (bind(socket_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&server_addr,
                sizeof(server_addr)) < 0) {
            close(socket_fd);
            printf("Server: Failed to bind ipv4 server socket.\n");
            return INVALID_SOCKET_FD;
        }
    }
    else if (socket_fd < 0) {
        printf("Server: Failed to create server socket.\n");
        return INVALID_SOCKET_FD;
    }

    if (listen(socket_fd, backlog) < 0) {
        close(socket_fd);
        printf("Server: Failed to set listen.\n");
        return INVALID_SOCKET_FD;
    }

    return socket_fd;
}



pthread_t temp;



void *number_two(void *sock)
{
    char buf[1024];
    int fd = *(int *)sock;
    int nread = read(fd, buf, 1024);
    write(STDOUT_FILENO, buf, nread);

    return NULL;
}



int main()
{
    pid_t pid;
    if ((pid = fork()) < 0) {
    }
    else if (pid > 0) {  // parent, server
        char buf[1024];
        int fd = create_tcp_server_socket(8787, false, 10, "zz");
        int new_fd = accept(fd, NULL, 0);
        pthread_create(&temp, NULL, number_two, (void *)&new_fd);
    }
    else {  // child, client
        uint32_t ip;
        struct hostent *hp = gethostbyname("localhost");
        memcpy(&ip, hp->h_addr_list[0], hp->h_length);

        struct sockaddr_in server_addr;
        memset((char *)&server_addr, 0, sizeof(server_addr));
        server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
        server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = ip;
        server_addr.sin_port = htons(8787);

        int fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
        connect(fd, (struct sockaddr *)&server_addr, sizeof(server_addr));

        write(fd, "abcd", 4);
    }

    pause();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thank you, Yun. Your code works, I'll try to understand what's wrong in my full code!